# PnP Script to get root folders of a SharePoint online document library and set unique permissions

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

We have the following:-

1. online document library which contains around 1000 root folders,

We want to run a Power Shell script which runs on the 1000 root folders ONLY (without the sub-folders) >> then set unique permissions on the roots folders >> get the current permissions Groups + Users >> grant them Read-Only.

Can anyone advice on such a Script ? Thanks

I have the following:-

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL="https://******.sharepoint.com/"
$FolderSiteRelativeURL = "/Shared Documents/"
 
#Connect to the Site collection
Connect-PnPOnline -URL $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
#Get the Folder from site relative URL
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderSiteRelativeURL
 
#Get all Subfolders of a folder - recursively
$SubFolders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderSiteRelativeURL -ItemType Folder -Recursive

ForEach($SubFolder in $SubFolders)
    {
If($SubFolder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
    Write-host "Folder is already with broken permissions!" -f Yellow
}
Else
{
    #Break Folder permissions - keep all existing permissions & keep Item level permissions
    $SubFolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($True,$True)
    Invoke-PnPQuery
 
    Write-host "Folder's Permission Inheritance is broken!!" -f Green
        /// Need the code which goes here......................   
}
    }
```

To get all the root folders, but how i can get the list of permissions assigned to the folder, and set its permission level to Read instead of Edit, Contribute or full access?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried this code:-

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL="https://***.sharepoint.com/"
$FolderSiteRelativeURL = "Shared Documents"
 
#Connect to the Site collection
Connect-PnPOnline -URL $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
#Get the Folder from site relative URL
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $FolderSiteRelativeURL
 
#Get all Subfolders of a folder - recursively
$SubFolders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderSiteRelativeURL -ItemType Folder -Recursive

ForEach($SubFolder in $SubFolders)
    {
If($SubFolder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
{
    Write-host "Folder is already with broken permissions!" -f Yellow
}
Else
{
Write-host "Else is running" -f Yellow
    #Break Folder permissions - keep all existing permissions & keep Item level permissions
    $SubFolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($True,$True)
    $RoleAssignments = $SubFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments
    ForEach($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments)
        {
            //extra code should goes here..
        }
 
    Write-host "Folder's Permission Inheritance is broken!!" -f Green   
}
    }
```

but i got this error:-

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or
> the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
> requested. At line:13 char:9
>
> - ForEach($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments)
> - ```
>       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], CollectionNotInitializedException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @Clive looks like i provided all the necessary info ... not sure why you did not like it

Comment: I don’t like or dislike it (this isn’t Facebook) - it’s off topic so I voted to close it, and left you a link to explain why it’s not an acceptable question. To clarify, as it seems you haven’t read the link: there is no “here are my requirements, do my work for me” service here. You need to post your code and explain where you’re stuck with it.

Comment: @Clive but when you vote to close means you did not like it, any way i edit my question with what i have done so far..

Comment: No it doesn’t, it means it’s off topic. Voting here is based on topicality, not on likes and dislikes. You’re thinking of social media, this isn’t that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following articles, first get all root folders from the library, and then cycle inside to change the user's permissions.

```
#Grant folder permissions to SharePoint Group
 Set-PnPfolderPermission -List $ListName -identity $FolderServerRelativeURL -AddRole "Read" -Group "<group name>"
```

Reference:
[Set Folder Permissions using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/09/sharepoint-online-set-folder-permissions-powershell.html#:%7E:text=Click%20on%20the%20%E2%80%9CGrant%20Permission,add%20permission%20to%20the%20folder.);
[PowerShell to Get Folder Permissions](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-folder-permissions.html)